# Image to base64 return null

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to convert the image into base64 but I get a null result, anyone has a clue? I found few examples how to take a pic from a camera and convert into b64 but i couldn't found anything how to convert image tag into b64.

```
<image @loaded="loaded" src="myimg.jpg">
var ImageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");

function loaded(args){    
let imageSource = ImageSourceModule.fromNativeSource(args.object.nativeElement);
console.log(imageSource.toBase64String('jpeg'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be getting null data because of coverting image before it is fully loaded. try converting image after it is fully loaded as shown in below snippet.

To convert image after it's load we are using `loaded` event and `isLoading` property of the Image.

```
loaded(args) {
    console.log(args.eventName);
    console.log(args.object);

    var img = args.object;

    console.log("img.isLoading: " + img.isLoading);
    console.log("img.isLoaded: " + img.isLoaded);
    if(img.isLoading){

        img.on("isLoadingChange", function (args) {
            console.log("isloading",args.value);
            console.log("isloaded",args.object.isLoaded);
            let img       = args.object;
            let imageSource= ImageSource.fromNativeSource(img);
            console.log(imageSource.toBase64String('jpeg'))
        });
    }else if(!img.isLoading&&img.isLoaded){
        let imageSource= ImageSource.fromNativeSource(img);
        console.log(imageSource.toBase64String('jpeg'))
    }else{
        console.log("image loading failed");
    }
}
```